# Issue in action bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Am creating  `mail client` application in which i include the library `actionbarsherlock` so that the `actionbar` will be found  on `top` of the `screen`,i want to include a `header` above the action bar. Is there any possibility ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the action bar itself is on the title bar :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no that is not possible. The [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) is made in a way it will always be shown at the top of the screen, mostly due to consistency of android applications. Thereby you can not just place a View above it. Your actionbar will always be above the layout you can define.

Comment: Yes, with getSupportActionBar().hide(). I advise you to look at the ActionBarSherlock samples http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html